# Python Pandas - Structuring my Data

Tags: python, pandas

I would like some advice please as I'm still new to Python, Pandas etc.

I have a DataFrame that I have created with the following code:

```
SS = [1,2,3,4,8]
ASP = [1,2,3,4]

store_training = pd.DataFrame(index = ASP, columns = SS)
```

I then have a nested loop that loops through every combination of `ss` and `asp` and fills in the DataFrame based on calculations.

Now, in order to remove noise from my dataset, I would like to repeat the process `N` times and then take the average for each combination of `ss` and `asp`.

My initial thought to save the results is to have a 3D DataFrame with one layer for each repetition, however, I don't believe these exist.

So, my question for you is how would you store this data for easy access, comprehension and analysis down the road?

Many thanks, please let me know if I could explain myself more clearly. I'm using Python 3.5 in Windows 10.

Specifically, I would like something like the following:

```
SS = [1,2,3,4,8]
ASP = [1,2,3,4]
repeats = np.arange(1,11,1)

store_training = pd.DataFrame(index = ASP, columns = SS)

for s in SS:
    for a in ASP:
        for r in repeats:
            # Apply math here
            # store_training.ix[a,s,r] = calculatedValue

# Analyse variance for each (s,a) combination in store_training over r
# Take mean of each (s,a) combination in store_training over r
# etc.
```

Comment: Have u checked out the pandas panel function. It can store a 3d array http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html

Comment: I wouldn't store all the intermediate data at all, I would iterate over the combinations lazily, and only store the final results in a dataframe. Perhaps you could be more explicit about what you mean, exactly, though. How are you looping, what *exactly* do you mean by a combination?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've updated my question with what I hope addresses your comment.